# Convert xml to object when only the wrapper tag is fixed

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have a string like below

```
<Ouput>
    <tag1>xxxxx</tag1>
    <tag2>xxxxx</tag2>
    <tag3>xxxxx</tag3>
</Ouput>
```

It is always surrounded by an OutPut tag, but the structure of the tags inside is not fixed. I want to convert the text above to an object like below

```
public class Output {
     private string content;
     // getter, setter...
}
```

My expectation is that the value of content will be as follows:

```
<tag1>xxxxx</tag1>
<tag2>xxxxx</tag2>
<tag3>xxxxx</tag3>
```

Because I only need to know content of OutPut tag is empty or not so I only want to get the content inside the OutPut tag. Is there any way to convert the content inside the OutPut as a string?